# Contacts Authorization Alert goes to background sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cncontactstore

I have an app where I am accessing Contacts Store ( address book ) and to show contacts I am using a tableView, before accessing I am asking for permission using Authorisation Alert, this alert is triggered from tap of a cell view of contacts table view. This cell tell to user about allowing permissions in order to see contacts in the tableview, once contacts are loaded this cell disappears. Mostly it appears/works fine , but sometimes it goes to background , and when I kill the app it appears on home screen of phone, is there a way to ensure that this doesnt happen ?

Comment: What do you mean 'it goes to background'?

Comment: @JackChamberlain it means UI screen of permission goes behind the main view controller with tableview and I have to close app to go to the permission alert.